# Problemas al recibir un JSON con etiquetas HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json, web

estoy tratando de recibir un json mediante ajax por get, pero cuando lo recibo, me imprime etiquetas antes, no entiendo bien porque.

[image: Codigo al recibir el json en ajax]

Codigo cuando envio el JSON

```
echo  json_encode($rpta1,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

[image: Esto logro imprimir.]

Codigo para obtener el json

```
<?php    
  //header('Content-Type: application/json');
   include("../conexion.php");
   include("../modelo/Publicaciones.php");


    //Conexion
    $obj = new Conexion;
    $conexion=$obj->conectar();
    //Informacion a editar


    // echo $email."-".$password;
    $objPubIL = new Publicaciones($conexion);
    //$rpta = array();
    $rpta1 = $objPubIL->MostrarPubDocIL();
    $rpta2 = $objPubIL->MostrarPubAdmIL();
    $rpta3 = $objPubIL->MostrarPubCasIL();
    // echo json_encode($rpta1);
    // echo json_encode($rpta2);
    // echo json_encode($rpta3);
    // var_dump($rpta);
    // die();

    // if($rpta1){
    //     $_SESSION['estado'] = 'Exito';
    //     header('location: ../InformacionLaboral.php?arreglo1='.serialize($rpta1)."&arreglo2=".serialize($rpta2)."&arreglo3=".serialize($rpta3));
    // }else{
    //     $_SESSION['estado'] = 'Error';
    //     echo "<script>alert('Problemas al solicitar el servicio');</script>";
    //     // echo "<script>window.location.href='../login.php'</script>";
    // }
     echo  json_encode($rpta1,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    // echo '<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    // echo '<script>
    //     $(document).ready(function() {

    //         var datar1=  "prueeba";

    //         $.ajax({  
    //             url: "../InformacionLaboral.php",                      
    //             method: "POST",   
    //             data: "datar1",
    //             datatype: "json",
    //           success: function(data)             
    //             {

    //                 window.location.href="../InformacionLaboral.php";    
    //             } 
    //       }); 
    //     });
    // </script>';
```

?>

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que *imprime etiquetas antes*?  ¿Te refieres al caracter `[`?  Eso es porque es un array JSON, no un objeto JSON. La diferencia es que el array JSON empieza por `[` y termina por `]`. En ese caso se accede al JSON poniendo la clave `0`, por ejemplo: `console.log(rpta1[0]);` A veces, cuando no se han puesto los encabezados adecuados, hay que parsear el JSON antes o poner bien los encabezados al devolver los datos al cliente.

Comment: Me refiero a que imprime etiquetas html, no se porque imprime esa parte. solo quiero el array json

Comment: Entiendo. Debes mostrar **el texto del archivo PHP completo** con el que manejas la respuesta. Parece que todas esas etiquetas están en tu PHP y por eso se muestran. No deben existir y el archivo PHP que llamas debe ser un archivo utilitario que no uses para otra cosa que para enviar / recibir datos y **cuya única salida por pantalla sea el JSON**. También, en la petición que haces con `$.get` debes poner que esperas datos del tipo JSON. Por favor edita la pregunta, quitando las imágenes (que no sirven de nada en este caso) y poniendo el texto del código. Gracias.

Comment: ahi, actualize mi pregunta.

Comment: La sigo viendo igualita. Con esa información es imposible ayudarte. Sustituye las imágenes por el texto completo del código PHP y el código Javascript. Y di si tus archivos son dos archivos distintos, no sea que estés intentando todo desde un mismo archivo.

Comment: Te dije que las imágenes no sirven de nada en estos casos, que debes poner el texto del código en la pregunta. O sea, copiar el texto y pegarlo en la pregunta. ¿Me explico? Viendo que incluyes archivos en el PHP , debes saber que esos archivos que incluyes no deben tener tampoco salida de texto,  con `echo, print` o etiquetas HTML.

Comment: Si ya las actualice, disculpa

Comment: El archivo parece correcto, pero, estos dos archivos que incluyes: `include("../conexion.php"); include("../modelo/Publicaciones.php");` no deben tener etiquetas HTML o salida por pantalla. Debes revisarlos. Tampoco los métodos que llamas pueden tener salida por pantalla. Esas etiquetas que aparecen vienen de alguno de esos archivos o métodos que usas en el PHP que recibe la petición.

Comment: Tenias razon, en el  archivo conexion, tenia una etiqueta html, pero estaban comentadas, no entiendo porque los imprimia igual? me podrias explicar esa parte.?

Comment: ¿Explicar qué parte? ¿Y qué hacen unas etiquetas HTML en un archivo de conexión? No deben existir, ni siquiera comentadas así que es mejor que borres esas etiquetas. Cuando se hace una petición vía Ajax, debes ser muy meticuloso controlando lo que sale por pantalla en todo el proceso de esa petición: **no debe salir nada más que lo que se pide**.  Y por favor por el código de `$.get` en texto para completar la mejora de tu pregunta. Como ya dije, las imágenes no sirven absolutamente de nada en estos casos.

Comment: Osea a pesar de estar comentadas las etiquetas html, me las imprimia en el JSON, ya las borre y ahora si me imprime norma, soy nuevo en ajax, te agradesco el tiempo. Gracias

Comment: Como ya te dije, todos los archivos que intervienen en la petición, también los que incluyes con `include` deben estar muy muy controlados, también los métodos de las clases. El archivo de conexión no debería tener tampoco el famoso `die` que todo el mundo usa copiándolo de los malos ejemplos de muchos sitios y hasta del Manual de PHP. Cualquier salida de texto por pantalla cuando lo que se espera es un JSON provocará el problema que has tenido en este caso o problemas aún mayores. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Y para la próxima, evita las imágenes, dando preferencia al texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las etiquetas HTML que aparecen son debidas a que las mismas se encuentran en cualquiera de los archivos que intervienen del lado del servidor:

- sea el archivo `publicacionInfLab.php`
- sea el archivo `conexion.php` puesto en el contexto mediante el `include`
- sea el archivo `Publicaciones.php`
- sea cualquier llamada de métodos

La norma es muy simple: cuando haces peticiones Ajax debes guardar un control estricto de lo que sale por pantalla, de forma que **la única salida por pantalla sea lo que se haya mandado a buscar a través de la petición**. Cualquier otra cosa que salga por pantalla, será mostrada del otro lado (en caso de que el tipo de dato esperado sea `html` o `text`)  o hará que el código falle cuando el tipo de dato esperado sea un `json` o un `xml`.

Debes por tanto revisar esos archivos. Un error muy común es por ejemplo en los archivos de conexión sacar mensajes de error por pantalla (usando el desfasado `die`). Si pides algo vía Ajax que usa la conexión y hay un fallo, y el mismo sale por pantalla con `die`, te dará error del lado del cliente.

Para corregir eso, debes controlar la conexión, devolviendo en caso de error un objeto `NULL`. Luego en el código que usa la conexión verificas primero si la conexión es nula o no, si es nula, devuelves un array con una clave de error dentro, o bien los datos correctos. En el cliente, puedes buscar la clave `error` en la respuesta para mostrar el error, o bien mostrar los datos. Esta sería una forma coherente de trabajar con peticiones Ajax, porque siempre tendrás en respuesta un objeto JSON. Si te fijas, así es como funcionan todas las APIs modernas.

Aquí la palabra clave es **coherencia**. Si la petición espera un JSON, debes cuidar que por pantalla, pase lo que pase, no salgo otra cosa que no sea un JSON y que éste sea válido, claro está.

Otra cosa que ayuda es poner un encabezado, cuando se espera del otro lado un JSON.

En tu caso sería algo así:

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($rpta1,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Espero te sirva y si tienes alguna duda lo puedes decir en comentarios.